# Items are misplaced in recyclerView after scrolling up or down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am working on a chat application. I am fetching the messages from firebase. Messages are placed accurately before scrolling up/down. But when i scroll all the items are misplaced.

Here is my OnBindViewHolder

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    String senderId=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    Messages messages=mMessageList.get(i);
    String fromUserId=messages.getFrom();
    String fromMessageType=messages.getType();}
```

I am loading the message in another activity.
First time they load correctly but misplace after scrolling. Please help me. I am not able to solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because after scrolling ids of recycler view items are messing up
Try by overriding following methods in Adapter

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
       return 1;
}
```

Comment: yeah i have these method but still problems occurs

Comment: Are you using Firebase Firestore or Realtime Database?

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot to add getItemId() method. Problem solved. Thanks alot. God bless you :)

Comment: Glad to help. You can surely upvote and approve the answer to thank. :)

Comment: You should NOT be returning unique `itemViewType` for each position. This violates the basic behavior of RecyclerView pattern (which is view recycling). You basically obliterate the performance by forcing `Adapter` to create new `ViewHolder` for each position.

Comment: @Pawel we can set it to single type for now and change to multiple type as per types of recyclerview items